# Covering a UIView with a UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, view

I have a UISearchBar, a UITableView and a MapKitView. At the beginning, the map view should appear right below the search bar, showing the current location.

Like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42T4U.jpg).

When the user starts typing, the map view should be covered by a table view, showing some address suggestions.

Like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fatp.png).

The table view should disappear only after the user has chosen an address or has canceled the edit, revealing again the map view.

I'm thinking about using an expandable table view and stick both views together, however, I would like the map view to be either covered or shown, instead of being pushed up and down by the expanding mechanism.

Is there a way to achieve this using the Interface Builder or do I need to create at least one of those views programmatically?

Comment: Expand your table not to full screen with using constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `UISearchController` to do what you're trying to achieve. Initialize an instance of the `UISearchController` class and set a `UITableViewController` as the `searchResultsController` and the other view controller would just have a map view and a search bar.

Take a look at [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/157864/uisearchcontroller-tutorial-getting-started) if you wanna know how to set up and use `UISearchController`